# UINavigationController is nil in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

In my main storyboard I have 1 Navigation controller and subsequent swift file NavigationCtr.swift.

The viewController is in different xib.

Now I want to push my viewController from the NavigationCtr class.

```
       let vcFirst = FirstViewController(nibName: "FirstViewController", bundle: nil)
    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vcFirst, animated: true)
```

I am getting a exception

**fatal error**: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

So when I trying to print from viewDidLoad

```
   print(self.navigationController)
```

in NavigationCtr.swift class it is giving nil. So nothing works

---

I created a new project in objective C and it works fine. 
Attached the storyboard image
Any hint in the direct direction is highly appreciated.
Note : - I am new to swift

[image]

Comment: Please show how are you pushing your ViewController from 'NavigationCtr' in your code.

Comment: In your image it is only showing the NavigationCtr ViewController and it is set to the entry point. So it does not look like you have added a NavigationController. You need to select the ViewController, select Edit -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller.

Comment: FRom the storyboard I have deleted the ViewController and put a navigationController. So the idea is main story board will have only navigationController and ViewCtr will be in different xibs

Comment: Why will the storyboard only have navigationController? Do what @totiG said; Create a ViewController in the storyboard, select it, then click Editor -> Embed in -> Navigation Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the main issue was using the self.navigationController

As my storyboard only had navigationController I should just self keyword.
as below

```
let vcFirst = FirstViewController(nibName: "FirstViewController", bundle: nil)
self.pushViewController(vcFirst, animated: true)
```

Answer (score -3):

For the first controller, set it as `rootController` instead of push (show).

```
self.navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vcFirst)
```

Or set its view controllers

```
self.navigationController = UINavigationController()
navigationController.setViewControllers([vcfirst], animated: true)
```

Comment: self.navigationCOntroller is a readonly property   @property(nullable, nonatomic,readonly,strong) UINavigationController *navigationController;

Comment: yes actually, you cannot set navigation controller like that.